# How to cache image in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios8

I am developing the picture gallery app. In the collection view, I display the thumb. Each time, I scroll the collection view, the app read and open the image again. After some times, there is memory warnings. I want to cache the image. Then when I scroll the collection view, the app read the cached image instead of opening a new one.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AllViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:IdAllCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *arrInfo = [self.arrThangkaInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Cell Image
    NSString *thumbImageName = [self getValue:@"thumb_image" forRecord:arrInfo];
    NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", self.thumbFolder, thumbImageName];
    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [cell.imageView setImage:originalImage];

    // Cell Label
    NSString *name = [self getValue:@"name" forRecord:arrInfo];

    [cell.nameLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [cell.nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [cell.nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell.nameLabel setText:name];

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return cell;
}
```